# jQuery delay not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, delay

I cant seem to get my text to update, with a delay of 0.8seconds.

```
function beginningText() {
 $('#bubbleText').text('H').delay(800);
$('#bubbleText').text('He');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` blocks code which chains from it on the same statement, but not code which comes on statements after it.

*Technically* the structure you want is this:

```
$('#bubbleText').text('H').delay(800).text('He');
```

***However***, this won't work.  For a very non-obvious reason (that I just had to look up).  `.delay()` operates on items that are "queued" in jQuery, such as animations and other things which, well, take time.  Setting text, or any other such "instant" operation, isn't "queued" and just happens immediately.

You can *manually* add operations to the queue with the `.queue()` function:

```
$('#bubbleText').text('H').delay(800).queue(function(){
    $('#bubbleText').text('He');
});
```

Comment: when the document loads, it just says "HE" straight away instead of "h" then "he"

Comment: @igetstuckalot: Interesting.  I just learned something new :)  I've updated the answer with a new example: https://jsfiddle.net/93vatb5v/

Comment: sorry to be annoying, but if i wanted to add something else to that queue ('hel','hell','hello') how would i do so?

Comment: @igetstuckalot: In that case you'd chain more calls to `.queue()` after the original.  Something like `blah().delay().queue(function(){}).delay().queue(function(){});`  It could get ugly fast, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want set timeout here and not delay. 
There is s

Created a fiddle for you 
https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/5d09nbLo/

Sample Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function beginningText() {

    $('#bubbleText').text('H');
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#bubbleText').text('HE') }, 3000);

   }
 beginningText();

});

<div id = "bubbleText"></div>
```

As per jQuery Documentation

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

So the keypoints to take away are

1. Use .delay() for jQuery effects including animations.
2. setTimeout() is best used for everything else. For example when you
   need to trigger an event at a certain elapsed time.

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning

Comment: Are there any benefits to declaring the function within Document ready?

Comment: The code inside document.ready will be executed after your document is loaded. If you dont wrap it inside ready then there may be a case that the script loads before the document is loaded. So there wont be anything named bubbleText and your code will look into it and will find nothing and will do nothing or may give you undefined if you try to do anything with it. Hope it helps

Comment: I get why the function call is in there, I was just wondering why the function declaration was there.

Comment: That can be moved outside.